# Jquery - AJAX results append to different elements?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using AJAX to call an external page, I'd like some of the return results to update one div, but the rest to update another.

Currently in the page I'm calling I'm just echoing the results and then using jquery to update the div's, but I can't get some output to one div and the rest to another.

I've tried similar to:

```
success : function(text) {
            if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf("msg") >= 0) $('#cmd').append(text)
                if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf("output") >= 0) $('#output').append(text)
            console.log(text)
        },
```

But this results with all data (text) being written to both DIV's

Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: If there is a pattern in your result which is consistent in all requests, you can split result into two different parts with either `split` function of String or `Reg Expressions`

Comment: Thanks. that has helped.. Please add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a pattern in your result which is consistent in all requests there is a chance to use `split` function of String or `Regular Expressions`.

I assume the result has the following pattern.

```
var result = 'text_related_to_first_part&text_related_to_second_part';
```

Then you can split it by `&` like this.

```
var parts = result.split('&');
var firstPart = parts[0];
var secondPart = parts[1];

// then you can append firstPart and secondPart wherever you want
```

Actually you need to have a split point.